# Проверить установлено ли соединение при неблокирующим connect

Tags: linux, c, сокет

Выполняется неблокирующий коннект. Под windows момент установки сокета может быть определен с помощью select, если сокет writable то соединение установлено. 
А как под linux? После инициалицации он сразу становится writable. И соответственно попытка записать в сокет что либо вызовет SIGPIPE.

```
int sockfd = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

int arg = ::fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL);
long flags = arg & ~O_NONBLOCK;
flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags);

struct sockaddr_in dest;
dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest.sin_port = htons(1111);
inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &dest.sin_addr);

int rc = ::connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr* )&dest, sizeof(dest));

fd_set fdWrite;
FD_ZERO(&fdWrite);
FD_SET(sockfd, &fdWrite);

struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec  = 1;
tv.tv_usec = 0;

rc = ::select(int(sockfd) + 1, 0, &fdWrite, 0, &tv);
int er = errno;

return 0;
```

Comment: А Вам точно нужен НЕ блокирующий сокет? Почему-то 75% начинающих работать с сокетами пытаются использовать именно неблокирующие. Но в реальных серверных приложениях таких сокетов нет, просто потому, что *select* специально для того и придуман, что бы отказаться от их использования! Специально, что бы уйти от алгоритмов опроса. Почитайте, что пишет Шон Уолтон в книге "Создание сетевых приложений в среде Linux. Он обсуждает там неблокирующие сокеты, но все примеры конкретных приложений написаны БЕЗ этого "ручного управления".

Comment: [mcve] для экспериментов помог бы вопросу...

Comment: Это очень странно, потому что у меня под Linux при connect сокет writable только после того как соединится. В данном случае никакой разницы между windows и linux нет

Comment: @Sergey Что то вы путаете. При работе select как раз блокирующие сокеты никогда не используются. Потому что не дай бог, вы захотите прочитать из блокирующего сокета 100 байт, когда там доступно для чтения только 99. Он вполне может вас заблокировать и до select вы не дойдете. При работе с select все сокеты в обязательном порядке переводятся в не блокирующий режим, после чего добавляются в списки select и никакого опроса, конечно не происходит. И автор вопроса то же ничего опрашивать не собирался, он же пишет про writable сокет, а об этом состоянии сокета сообщает как раз select

Comment: @Sergey Кстати, если сокет блокирующий, то connect гарантированно заблокирует весь поток до момента как он установит соединение, что для асинхронного приложения не допустимо

Comment: @Mike *connect гарантированно заблокирует весь поток до момента как он установит соединение* - Три вопроса (предлагаю подумать): 1) Какой поток? 2) Что Вы собираетесь читать из неблокирующего сокета, если данных нет?  3) КУда Вы собираетесь писать, если сокет не готов к записи? :-)

Comment: Использовать неблокирующие сокеты можно можно только в однопоточном сервере. Да и то - если Вам очень хочется геммороя :-) Поймите, *select* был придуман для ОБЛЕЧЕНИЯ жизни программистам. Надо просто один раз сесть и разобраться с ним!

Comment: @Sergey 1. тот поток, который его вызвал. 2,3 - читать и писать разумеется можно только то, что есть и только если в бефах сокета есть место. А узнать, что с сокетом стоит работать можно как раз у select

Comment: @Sergey "_Использовать неблокирующие сокеты можно можно только в однопоточном сервере_" ... nginx посмотрите, отличный пример многопоточного сервера, в котором при этом каждый поток держит 1024 соединения одновременно, разумеется на неблокирующих сокетах. (сомневаюсь что там прям таки select, в серъезных задачах по возможности используют его старшего брата - epoll)

Comment: @Mike *разумеется на неблокирующих сокетах. (сомневаюсь что там прям таки selec)* - С *nginx* я не разбирался. Но вот передо мной исходы значительно более простого сервера - *boa* : https://github.com/gpg/boa Скачайте себе, поищите там *select* и *O_NONBLOCK* в каталоге *src*.

Comment: @Mike *тот поток, который его вызвал*. Если *select* был вызван в главном потоке, в параметрах fd_set которого перечислены ВСЕ (!!!) сокеты, то что Вы собрались делать, если ни один(!!!) из них не готов?

Comment: @Sergey Конечно ничего, select заблокирует поток до тех пор пока на один из сокетов не будет готов или пока не истечет указанный таймаут. Правда сути это не меняет. сокеты все равно считаются не блокирующими. И ни о каком "ручном управлении", о котором вы пишете в первом комментарии речи так же нет. Все что спрашивает автор "почему select считает, что в сокет, который еще устанавливает соединение, можно писать". (на что у меня ответа нет, потому что select такого считать не должен)

Comment: пример бессмысленный — зачем ждать сокет без `listen()` или `connect()`... к тому же он __не__-неблокирующий.... ничего удивительного, что он сразу возвращает ошибку...

Comment: @Sergey демонстрировать сервер 18-летней давности — так себе идея по-моему. Но смотрите ещё раз: упоминаемый вами `connect` заблокирует поток, а в это время, возможно, уже существуют сотни ранее подключенных других сокетов, которые можно было бы запихнуть в `select` и которые готовы читать и писать. Но их невозможно читать и писать, потому что connect заблокировал поток! Так что лично я в общем-то вообще не понимаю, о чём вы говорите, по-моему вы противоречите сами себе. И да, нет смысла делать многопоточный синхронный сервер, когда можно сделать однопоточный асинхронный :)

Comment: @Rikitikitavi Не надо добавлять в списки ожидания select сокеты с которыми вы еще точно не знаете что будет происходить. Сокет можно добавлять в список на запись только после того как поставили на него nonblock и вызвали функцию connect. Если вы сокет только создали но ничего с ним не делали, то select тут же вернет управление и скажет, что в него можно писать. И да, в этом случае поведение windows/linux может различаться.

Comment: @Mike добавил перевод в неблокирующий режим и вызов connect. Все равно select возвращает 1.

Comment: @Rikitikitavi А на 127.0.0.1:1111 что нибудь есть, к чему connect бы шел очень долго ? Обратите внимание, если при connect будет ошибка, то select то же вернет его. Попробуйте отлаживаться делая connect на какой нибудь адрес в интернете, который долго не отвечает

Comment: @Mike Так в  том то и проблема, что в данном примере по этому адресу ничего нет, connect ошибку не вернул(и это правильно) и select тоже(errno == 0). В реальном приложении сначала создается множество сокетов, они переводятся в неблокирующий режим, и вызывается connect. Далее через select проверяется на writable. В моем примере я воспроизвел эту схему. И логика работы select мне не понятна. Как мне проверить что попытка записи в сокет не вызовет SIGPIPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дабы не тянуть резину наводящими вопросами я просто процитирую [`man 2 connect`](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=connect&category=2&russian=0)

> ### ОШИБКИ
>
> ...
> **EINPROGRESS**
>
> Сокет  является  неблокирующим, а соединение не может быть установлено немедленно. Можно использовать select(2) или poll(2), чтобы закончить соединение, установив ожидание возможности записи в сокет. После того, как select(2) сообщит о такой возможности, используйте getsockopt(2), чтобы прочитать флаг SO_ERROR на уровне SOL_SOCKET, чтобы определить, успешно ли завершился  connect()  (в  этом  случае  SO_ERROR  равен  нулю)  или неудачно (тогда SO_ERROR равен одному из обычных кодов ошибок, перечисленных здесь, и объясняет причину неудачи).